# Rails Group Action on Selected Items in List - Best Way

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, action

I have an inbox table of emails.
In each row there is a delete button:
<%=link_to 'Delete', email, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this e-mail?' %>

Note: email here is the email object passed to page.

Now. I want to have a check box in each row, and a common delete button at the bottom. I put the checkbox in each row in as:
<%= check_box_tag('email', email)%>

I don't know how to go about doing a common Delete button at the bottom.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap this in a form (say multi_delete), process the checked email ids passed to the action.

You will need to modify this but generally:

```
#multi_delete action to be defined in config/routes.rb

#in your view
= form_tag(:action => :multi_delete) do
  - @emails.each do |email|
    = check_box_tag('emails[]', email.id)
  = submit_tag('Delete', :confirm => "Go for it?")

#in your controller
def multi_delete
  Email.destroy_all("id IN ?", params[:emails])
  redirect_to :action => "index"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. For those needing more details, a very similar approach is outlined in RailsCast #52: http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes.